# In C++ Help using setprecision()

Tags: c++, decimal

When I run the program, the `setprecision` works with all of the variables. I am trying to get the variable `secondsinput` to be a whole number. I have already tried setting that variable as an int but that screws up the math. Any ideas ?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double outputminutes, outputhours, outputdays, secondsinput;

cout << "Please enter the number of seconds: ";
cin >> secondsinput;
cout << endl;

outputminutes = secondsinput / 60;
outputhours = secondsinput / 3600;
outputdays = secondsinput / 86400;

cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;

if (secondsinput > 60 && secondsinput < 3600)
        cout << secondsinput << " seconds is " 
             << outputminutes << " minutes." 
             << endl << endl;

else if (secondsinput > 3600 && secondsinput < 86400)
        cout << secondsinput << " seconds is " 
             << outputhours << " hours." 
             << endl << endl;
else if (secondsinput > 86400)
    cout << secondsinput << " seconds is " 
             << outputdays << " days." 
             << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `secondsinput` an `int`, since that's how you want it input and displayed. Just fix the math. For example:

```
outputminutes = secondsinput / 60.0;
outputhours = secondsinput / 3600.0;
outputdays = secondsinput / 86400.0;
```

or

```
outputminutes = static_cast<double>(secondsinput) / 60;
outputhours = static_cast<double>(secondsinput) / 3600;
outputdays = static_cast<double>(secondsinput) / 86400;
```

Comment: I somehow knew that and answer was that simple, but I just don't know enough about c++ to understand the things like that. Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you don't like the verboseness of the `static_cast`, you can use functional style casts for this kind of benign casting: `double(secondsinput) / 60`